# Get a value of a column when another column meets a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-athena, presto

```
column1       column2     column3  
    aa            1        x              
    aa            2        x              
    aa            3        y              
    aa            4        y              
    bb            1        x              
    bb            2        y              
    bb            3        y  
    cc            1        x
    cc            2        z
    cc            3        z
```

Then I want a column col4 which gives the value of minimum value of col2 when the col3='y' partitioned by col1. The original data set is not in order

```
column1       column2 column3         column4
    aa            1        x              3 
    aa            2        x              3
    aa            3        y              3
    aa            4        y              3
    bb            1        x              2
    bb            2        y              2
    bb            3        y              2
    cc            1        x              NULL
    cc            2        z              NULL
    cc            3        z              NULL
```

I want to get the column2 value when column3 at first has a value 'y' for each ID. The real table is complex and big. I tried using `least(case when...) with over partition by group by`, but it throws error as 'Over' is not expected here. If I use group by, I get error that many other categorical columns are not grouped. It works only with any function applied to column like below, but it does not give me the required result.

```sql
least(case when (lag( column3) over (partition by column1 order by column2))='y' 
then column2 else NULL end ) as required_column_values from t
```

Comment: What results do you want?  I don't understand what you are really asking for.

Comment: required_column_values are my "Required result" which is actually derived from col2 based on col3 values and it should be partitioned on col1

Comment: I have made the example more clear

Answer (score 1):

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can do it with `MIN()` window function:

```
SELECT *,
       MIN(CASE WHEN column3 = 'y' THEN column2 END) OVER (PARTITION BY column1) column4
FROM tablename
```

For previous versions use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (SELECT MIN(t2.column2) FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.column1 = t1.column1 AND t2.column3 = 'y') column4
FROM tablename t1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c56d3bd4e4491e19557abcbe14e270f).